# Defining classes with several API versions together

Tags: raku, mop

That's not apparently possible...

```
role Versioned {
    method version () {
        return self.^api;
    }
}

class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<0> does Versioned {}
class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> does Versioned {}

say WithApi:api<0>.new.version;
say WithApi:api<1>.new.version;
```

This dies with

```
==SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/jmerelo/progs/perl6/my-perl6-examples/api-versioned.p6
Redeclaration of symbol 'WithApi'
at /home/jmerelo/progs/perl6/my-perl6-examples/api-versioned.p6:11
------> 1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> does Versioned⏏ {}
```

So is it even possible to `use` classes with different `api`s, same name in a single program?

*Update*: if they are included in different files, this is the error obtained:

```
P6M Merging GLOBAL symbols failed: duplicate definition of symbol WrongType
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things are creating a problem in this example:

- `class` is by default `our`, which causes a name clash
- the short name of the class is the same in the outer namespace, causing a clash

If we adapt the code slightly:

```
role Versioned {
    method version () {
        return self.^api;
    }
}

my constant one = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> does Versioned {}
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> does Versioned {}

say one.version;  # 1
say two.version;  # 2
```

I did find that there is a bug for `:api<0>`.  Apparently this is considered to be equivalent to **no** `:api` setting, resulting in an empty string rather than `0`.

Comment: How would that translate to creating two files with different api versions of a class? The exported symbol would need to have a different name?

Comment: Until we implement support for `:as`, one way of doing this would be to import the files in two different blocks.  Something like: `constant Foo = do { use Test; Test }; dd Foo; # Test`