# Signature can't be resolved when it's aliased to a constant

Tags: raku, dispatch

As a follow up to [this question about using different APIs in a single program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039465/defining-classes-with-several-api-versions-together), [Liz Mattijsen suggested to use constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040292/891440). Now here's a different use case: let's try to create a [`multi`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/multi) that differentiates by API version, like this:

```
class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1>  {}
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}

multi sub get-api( WithApi $foo where .^api() == 1 ) {
    return "That's version 1";
}

multi sub get-api( WithApi $foo where .^api() == 2 ) {
    return "That's version deuce";
}

say get-api(WithApi.new);
say two.new.^api;
say get-api(two.new);
```

We use a constant for the second version, since both can't be together in a single symbol space. But this yields this error:

```
That's version 1
2
Cannot resolve caller get-api(WithApi.new); none of these signatures match:
    (WithApi $foo where { ... })
    (WithApi $foo where { ... })
  in block <unit> at ./version-signature.p6 line 18
```

So `say two.new.^api;` returns the correct api version, the caller is `get-api(WithApi.new)`, so `$foo` has the correct type and the correct API version, yet the multi is not called? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Doing some messing about with your code and I think the issue is the `WithApi` in the `multi` declarations are tied to the defined `:api<1>` class that's at the package level.

The `two` constant defines it's own locally scoped `:api<2>` version of `WithApi` that whilst it has the same name doesn't match the token used in the multi dispatch.

Comment: At a guess,`multi sub get-api( WithApi $foo where .^api() == 2 )` needs to be `multi sub get-api( two $foo where .^api() == 2 )`.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington but $foo is correctly identified, at least in the error, as WithApi, is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** [JJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077919/891440) is a run-time `where` clause that calls a pair of methods on the argument of concern. Everyone else's answers do the same job, but using compile-time constructs that provide better checking and much better performance. This answer blends my take with Liz's and Brad's.

## Key strengths and weaknesses of JJ's answer

In JJ's answer, all the logic is self-contained within a `where` clause. This is its sole strength relative to the solution in everyone else's answers; it adds no LoC at all.

JJ's solution comes with two significant weaknesses:

- Checking and dispatch overhead for a `where` clause on a parameter is incurred at run-time<sup>1</sup>. This is costly, even if the predicate isn't. In JJ's solution the predicates *are* costly ones, making matters even worse. And to cap it all off, the overhead in the worse case when using *multiple* dispatch is the *sum* of *all* the `where` clauses used in *all* the `multi`s.
- In the code `where .^api() == 1 &&  .^name eq "WithApi"`, 42 of the 43 characters are duplicated for each `multi` variant. In contrast a non-`where` clause type constraint is much shorter and would not bury the difference. Of course, JJ could declare `subset`s to have a similar effect, but then that would eliminate the sole strength of their solution without fixing its most significant weakness.

## Attaching compile-time metadata; using it in multiple dispatch

Before getting to JJ's problem in particular, here are a couple variations on the general technique:

```
role Fruit {}                             # Declare metadata `Fruit`

my $vegetable-A = 'cabbage';
my $vegetable-B = 'tomato' does Fruit;    # Attach metadata to a value

multi pick (Fruit $produce) { $produce }  # Dispatch based on metadata

say pick $vegetable-B;                    # tomato
```

Same again, but parameterized:

```
enum Field < Math English > ;

role Teacher[Field] {}                    # Declare parameterizable metadata `Teacher`

my $Ms-England  = 'Ms England'; 
my $Mr-Matthews = 'Mr Matthews';

$Ms-England  does Teacher[Math];
$Mr-Matthews does Teacher[English];

multi field (Teacher[Math])    { Math }
multi field (Teacher[English]) { English }

say field $Mr-Matthews;                   # English
```

I used a `role` to serve as the metadata, but that's incidental. The point was to have metadata that can be attached at compile-time, and which has a type name so dispatch resolution candidates can be established at compile-time.

## A compile-time metadata version of JJ's run-time answer

The solution is to declare metadata and attach it to JJ's classes as appropriate.

A variation on Brad's solution:

```
class WithApi1 {}
class WithApi2 {}

constant one = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> is WithApi1 {}

constant two = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> is WithApi2 {}

constant three = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.2>:api<1> is WithApi1 {} 

multi sub get-api( WithApi1 $foo ) { "That's api 1" }

multi sub get-api( WithApi2 $foo ) { "That's api deuce" }

say get-api(one.new); # That's api 1
say get-api(two.new); # That's api deuce
say get-api(three.new); # That's api 1
```

An alternative is to write a single parameterizable metadata item:

```
role Api[Version $] {}

constant one = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> does Api[v1] {}

constant two = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> does Api[v2] {}

constant three = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.2>:api<v1> does Api[v1] {} 

multi sub get-api( Api[v1] $foo ) { "That's api 1" }

multi sub get-api( Api[v2] $foo ) { "That's api deuce" }

say get-api(one.new); # That's api 1
say get-api(two.new); # That's api deuce
say get-api(three.new); # That's api 1
```

## Matching ranges of versions

In a comment below JJ wrote:

> If you use `where` clauses you can have `multi`s that dispatch on versions up to a number (so no need to create one for every version)

The `role` solution covered in this answer can also dispatch on version ranges by adding another role:

```
role Api[Range $ where { .min & .max ~~ Version }] {}

...

multi sub get-api( Api[v1..v3] $foo ) { "That's api 1 thru 3" }

#multi sub get-api( Api[v2] $foo ) { "That's api deuce" }
```

This displays `That's api 1 thru 3` for all three calls. If the second multi is uncommented it takes precedence for `v2` calls.

Note that the `get-api` routine dispatch is still checked and candidate resolved at compile-time despite the fact the role signature includes a `where` clause. This is because the run-time for running the role's `where` clause is during compilation of the `get-api` routine; when the `get-api` routine is *called* the role's `where` clause is no longer relevant.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> In [Multiple Constraints](https://design.raku.org/S12.html#Multiple_constraints), Larry wrote:

> For 6.0.0 ... any structure type information inferable from the `where` clause will be ignored [at compile-time]

But for the future he conjectured:

```
my enum Day ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

Int $n where 1 <= * <= 5    # Int plus dynamic where
Day $n where 1 <= * <= 5    # 1..5
```

> The first `where` is considered dynamic not because of the nature of the comparisons but because `Int` is not finitely enumerable. [The second constraint] ... can calculate the set membership at compile time because it is based on the `Day` enum, and hence [the constraint, including the `where` clause] is considered static despite the use of a `where`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211467/discussion-on-answer-by-raiph-signature-cant-be-resolved-when-its-aliased-to-a).

Answer (score 6):

The solution is really simple: also alias the "1" version:

```
my constant one = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> {}
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}

multi sub get-api(one $foo) {
    return "That's version 1";
}

multi sub get-api(two $foo) {
    return "That's version deuce";
}

say one.new.^api;     # 1
say get-api(one.new); # That's version 1
say two.new.^api;     # 2
say get-api(two.new); # That's version deuce
```

And that also allows you to get rid of the `where` clause in the signatures.

Mind you, you won't be able to distinguish them by their given name:

```
say one.^name;  # WithApi
say two.^name;  # WithApi
```

If you want to be able to do that, you will have to set the name of the meta-object associated with the class:

```
my constant one = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> {}
BEGIN one.^set_name("one");
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}
BEGIN two.^set_name("two");
```

Then you will be able to distinguish by name:

```
say one.^name;  # one
say two.^name;  # two
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is really not the solution. That does not explain why the type is correctly detected as `get-api(WithApi.new)`. Is it because the error message uses ^name, but signature uses the symbol name?

Comment: Essentially, type checking internally does not use names at all.  Apart from `where` clauses and roles, it is basically `sub istype(\a,\b) { return True if nqp::eqaddr(b,$_) for a.^mro; False }`.

Comment: @ElizabetMattijsen my point is that in this case, we need to use names.

Answer (score 4):

Only one thing can be in a given namespace.

I assume the whole reason you are putting the second declaration into a constant and declaring it with `my` is that it was giving you a redeclaration error.

The thing is, that it should **still** be giving you a redeclaration error.
Your code shouldn't even compile.

You should have to declare the second one with `anon` instead.

```raku
class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> {}
constant two = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}
```

It would then be obvious why what you are trying to do doesn't work.
The second declaration is never installed into the namespace in the first place.
So when you use it in the second `multi` sub it is declaring that its argument is the same type as the first class.

(Even when you are using `my` in your code it isn't managing to install it into the namespace.)

---

You are assuming that the namespace is a flat namespace.
It isn't.

You can have a class that has one name, but is only ever accessible under another.

```raku
our constant Bar = anon class Foo {}

sub example ( Bar $foo ) {
    say $foo.^name; # Foo
}
example( Bar );
```

Raku installs the class into the namespace for you as a convenience.
Otherwise there would be a lot of code that looked like:

```raku
our constant Baz = class Baz {}
```

You are trying to use the namespace while at the same time trying to subvert the namespace.
I don't know why you expect that to work.

---

A quick way to get your exact code to work as you wrote it, is to declare that the second class is a subclass of the first.

```raku
class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> {}
constant two = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> is WithApi {}
#                                                                   ^________^
```

Then when the second `multi` checks that its argument is of the first type, it still matches when you give it the second.

This isn't great.

---

There isn't really a built-in way to do exactly what you want.

You could try to create a new meta type that can create a new type that will act like both classes.

I personally would just alias them both to independent names.

```raku
constant one = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1> {}
constant two = anon class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}
```

If you are loading them from modules:

```raku
constant one = BEGIN {
   # this is contained within this block
   use WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1>;

   WithApi # return the class from the block
}
constant two = BEGIN {
   use WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2>;
   WithApi
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but you are putting the focus on the wrong thing, which is declaration of the class with different APIs. I don't really care about that. I assume that they are declared in different files and they are included independently. But whatever is included, I want a multi to answer to it.

Comment: @jjmerelo They are two different classes. The only thing they have in common is the meta name attribute. They are not linked in any way. They cannot be stored in the namespace as a single unifying thing. You have to store them in separate variables/names.

Comment: That's true, but I don't need to have them stored at the same time. I want to write a multi that's valid for any of them.

Comment: @jjmerelo They are different objects. They only way to write one that works for all of them is to write one that is typed for a common super type. Which would be `Any`, or `Mu`. You can't do what you want to do without adding features to Raku in a module. That the two classes have the same short name is a coincidence as far as Raku is concerned.

Answer (score -4):

Elizabeth Mattijsen [answer above game me a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075091/891440). Signatures match symbol, not symbol name. However, when you alias (using a constant) to a new name, you still keep the name. Let's use this to have an uniform multi call where the only thing that changes is the api version:

```
class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1>  {}
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}
my constant two = my class WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2> {}
my constant three =  my class WithApi:ver<0.0.2>:api<1> {}

multi sub get-api( $foo where .^api() == 1 &&  .^name eq "WithApi" ) {
    return "That's version 1";
}

multi sub get-api( $foo where .^api() == 2 && .^name eq "WithApi") {
    return "That's version deuce";
}

say get-api(WithApi.new); # That's version 1
say get-api(two.new); # That's version deuce
say get-api(three.new); # # That's version 1
```

Again following Elizabeth's answer in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040292/891440), constants are used for the new versions to avoid namespace clashes, but the multis will be selected solely based in api version in a relatively type-safe way, without needing to use the aliased symbols in the signature. Even if you invent a new constant to alias WithApi with any metadata, the multi will still be selected based on api version (which is what I was looking for).

Comment: Type checking does not use names, unless you have a `where` clause that does that.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would want to dispatch on a `where` clause on the module meta-objects `api` value, instead of just dispatching on the two different types that can co-exist in the same namespace because they are exposed with two different names.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen which is precisely what I'm proposing here. I don't want to create two different types or two different aliases, I want to dispatch on api. Just imagine the same code is used with different versions of the API.

Comment: "Signatures match symbol, not symbol name." They smart match *some aspect of whatever object a symbol is bound to*, never a symbol itself. Symbols are things the *compiler* cares about, not really your code, except inasmuch as the compiler insists that a symbol refers to one and only one thing at a time.

Comment: "I don't want to create two different types". Presumably you're thinking `WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<1>` is (at some level of abstraction) the same type as 
`WithApi:ver<0.0.1>:auth<github:JJ>:api<2>`. But they are fundamentally different types because of the different `:api` bits. You cannot alter that.

Comment: @jjmerelo but effectively dispatching on `:api` value is exactly what my solution provides?  *confused*

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen but it fails unless you use the newly defined constant names, and you need to know them. I'm updating this right now.

Comment: @raiph they are, but you are you will need to know what you have aliased it to (or anyone else) to write the code. In my last version, that's not needed.